# Can nonstick pans go in the oven?

Tags: non-stick

I have a heavy bottomed sauté pan with a non-stick surface (could be Teflon). The handle is stainless steel and there are no plastic or rubber parts.

Can this go in the oven? If so, what are safe temperatures for a non-stick surface?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some pans have 'oven safe' labels on the bottom. That may help.

If not: DuPont studies show that at 446°F Teflon starts offgassing toxic gasses (Multiple sources).

Generally, I wouldn't put my non-stick pans in: use stainless.

Comment: "The recommended maximum use temperature for cookware with Teflon® nonstick coating is 500°F (260°C)."  http://www2.dupont.com/Teflon/en_US/products/safety/cookware_safety.html

Comment: Also oven safe: iron (cast or mineral), aluminum

Answer (score 2):

Nonstick pans are generally not good in the oven.

In my experience, the best thing to use is a cast-iron pan, which can go in and out of the oven with no worries. I'm just generally to lazy to use it, because I have to season it again.

Comment: Why would you have to season a pan after a trip in the oven?

Answer (score -1):

My Teflon pans say they are safe to 350.  Try looking up your pans online to see what the manufacturer recommends.

Comment: "safe to 350"... they're basically saying they aren't oven safe, then.  :D

Comment: Centigrade or Fahrenheit?