# Are hard anodized aluminum pans oven-safe?

Tags: food-safety, oven, chemistry

I have a full metal "hard anodized aluminum" pan which I'd like to use in the oven. I heard *non-stick pans in the oven are unsafe*.

This pan comes with: **no** "oven-safe" label, a metal handle on the pan, a glass lid with a plastic handle on it. Because of the glass lid with plastic handle, I assume it's not designed to go into an oven.

Can I still safely use this pan in the oven?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  For us to answer your question though, we're going to need the specific manufacturer and model of your pan, and maybe a link to their website.

Comment: Whatever stands on a stove flame should be oven safe, isn't? Not lid included, though.

Comment: @FuzzyChef I'm not new to SA. To maintain with community standards, I've decided to keep this question generic. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: @Alchimista **Not every pan is safe in the oven!** Non-stick pans (teflon?) are dangerous in an oven. See the answers to [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4972/can-nonstick-pans-go-in-the-oven)

Comment: Xunie: the bot thinks you're new.

Comment: Xunie: in that case: we still need more information to answer your question.  What kind of plastic?  Also, nonstick cookware is fine in the oven below 200C.

Comment: There is no plastic. Read the question carefully. I said the pan was "fully metallic".

Comment: Xunue you asked for a anodized aluminum not for Teflon.

Comment: "with a plastic handle on it"

Comment: The lid has a plastic handle, not the pan!

Answer (score 3):

An anodized finish is chemically stable. It does not decompose. It is nontoxic. High heat levels will not damage the anodized finish. Anodized surfaces are heat-resistant to the melting point of aluminium (1,221°F).

*Source: http://www.yourcookwarehelper.com/cookware-college/healthy-cookware-safe-cookware/is-anodized-aluminum-cookware-considered-safe-cookware/*

The issue you will have is if the rest of the pan is safe, such as the handle.
more information on this can be found here.

https://foodal.com/kitchen/pots-pots-skillets-guides-reviews/bare-aluminum-and-nonstick-cookware/choosing-the-best/

Answer (score -2):

Worth mentioning that any aluminum pans passed down through a family should be researched prior to using. I remember my father throwing away the only pan he would make fudge in because our local news featured a story about aluminum being unsafe for cooking. Newer pans would not have this issue. However, if you brought home Grandpa's Dutch Oven... double check with the manufacturer to make sure it's safe.

[How Toxic is Aluminum Cookware](https://www.cancerschmancer.org/blog/fran/how-toxic-aluminum-cookware)